# Null value getting passed to controller from javascript

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I checked couple of posts in SO and changed my code according to few suggestions still it is not working.

I am building an ASP.NET Core MVC application. When executed, the View presents a list of rows with ID. Each row has a corresponding button and it is required to pass the ID of the row whose button was clicked.

In the View, I have made call to a JS function as below:

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Update Status" class="ids" data-id="@sheet.ID" onClick="sendId(@sheet.ID)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

The JS function is as below:

```
    function sendId(id) {
        var rowId = parseInt(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/UpdateStatus/' + rowId,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function() { alert('Success'); },
            error: function() { alert('Error'); }
       });
       }
```

The controller action method is hit when button is clicked but it also triggers the error function of the above javascript code and it passes null to the action method.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UpdateStatus/{id}")]
        public void UpdateStatus(string mID)
        {
            // Do something
        }
```

** Edited **

Posting complete controller code on demand.

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

     
        [Route("~/UpdateStatus/{id}")]
        public void UpdateStatus([FromQuery] string mID)
        {
            // Do Something
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Index")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //TemplateData template = new TemplateData();
            List<TemplateData> templateList = new List<TemplateData>();
            templateList = ImportExcel();
            return View(templateList.AsEnumerable());
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

        private List<TemplateData> ImportExcel()
        {
            // Read Excel
            // path to your excel file
            string path = "C:\\ExcelData\\Results.xlsx";
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo);
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Data"];

            List<TemplateData> templateList = new List<TemplateData>();
 

            // get number of rows and columns in the sheet
            int rowCount = ws.Dimension.Rows; // 20
            int ColCount = ws.Dimension.Columns; // 7

            // loop through the worksheet rows and columns
            for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
            {
                TemplateData template = new TemplateData();
                template.ID = ws.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString();

                if (ws.Cells[row,6].Value != null)
                {
                    template.EmpName = ws.Cells[row, 6].Value.ToString();
                }

                if (ws.Cells[row, 7].Value != null)
                {
                    template.WareHouse= ws.Cells[row, 7].Value.ToString();
                }

                if (ws.Cells[row, 12].Value != null)
                {
                    template.Observation = ws.Cells[row, 12].Value.ToString();
                }

                templateList.Add(template);
            }

            return templateList;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can print out the error information by using `error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR.responseText);`. You can also use the browsers debugging tools to check the response from the server. Right now, you haven't shown us what that error is, so we can't diagnose.

Comment: I see your controller function is returning `void`. This might be a problem as you're not sending anything back to the ajax. try sending back a 200 response if `UpdateStatus` worked properly and a 400 (bad request data) or 500 ( server encountered a problem writing to the database or something) response as appropriate if `UpdateStatus` didn't perform properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need ajax, but if you still want it you have to remove type="submit" from button

```
<td>
 <input id="btnSubmit" value="Update Status" class="ids" onClick="sendId(@sheet.ID)" />
</td>
```

fix your ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/UpdateStatus/' + id,
        type: 'GET',
       success: function() { alert('Success'); },
        error: function() { alert('Error'); }
   });
```

and remove Post from the action and fix the route

```
[Route("~/UpdateStatus/{id}")]
public IActionResult UpdateStatus(string id)
{
    // Do something
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Still passing NULL

Comment: Can you post the whole controller pls?

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: @RKh Remove [FromQuery] pls. It is not in my answer

Comment: I removed. I was trying the other answer. But still not working.

Comment: @RKh If you change everytning according to my answer, and your Id is not empty or null, you will get Id value in the action. You should never mix the answers

Comment: I changed everything as yours, Javascript now throwing Success msg but the controller parameter is getting value of NULL passed.

Comment: it is impossible. Can you add  alert(id); before ajax and check the value?

Comment: Before AJAX, the value is coming but when AJAX hits controller, the ID is not getting passed. I rechecked. Entire code like yours.

Comment: did you change mID to  id? It is impossible that id could be null , because in this case you would get 404 error.

Comment: Jack pointed that the parameter name of action method is different than the JS parameter. Make it same fixed the issue. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the name of the parameter to match the route, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UpdateStatus/{id}")]
public void UpdateStatus(string id)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Tried. This too not working. BTW, I have added complete Controller code above.

Comment: @RKh You still need to fix the name of the parameter. You have `id` in the route and `mID` as the parameter variable name. They need to be the same.

Comment: Oh. Didn't know that. Let me try.

Comment: Thanks Thanks. It worked. But I cannot mark two answers as answers. The JS change of the other user also worked. Giving thumps up to you.

Comment: @RKh Looking at it again, the `[FromQuery]` shouldn't be necessary. So probably it was just the parameter name that was causing the issue. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I removed FromQuery and it is working. Parameter difference was causing the issue.